# Stop Button Functionaliity while in BUFFERING_STATE_ENTERED

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flv

I have a video player that when buttons are pressed a video loads and plays. Every once in a while when I button mash  I am able to get mulitple videos playing at once. I thought I had set the code up to remove all children before loading another video.

I have a feeling that my issues can ultimatly be fixed using the BUFFERING_STATE_ENTERED listener.

Is there a good way to disable all buttons on the screen while BUFFERING_STATE_ENTERED is active and turn everything back on once BUFFERING_STATE_ENTERED is complete?

//AS A QUICK FIX I AM LOADING A TRANSPARENT IMAGE OVER MY BUTTON AREA AND REMOVING THE IMAGE ON START, 
PUTTING IT BACK WHEN THE USER SELECTS A NEW VIDEO AND IT GOES INTO BUFFER_STATE_ENTERED. THIS KEEPS THEM FROM 
HITTING BUTTONS. 
    THIS WAS NOT MEANT TO BE PERMANENT.**

```
var ButtonBlock:empty_png = new empty_png;
ButtonBlock.x = 1550;
my_player.addEventListener(VideoEvent.BUFFERING_STATE_ENTERED, bufferPlay);
function bufferPlay(e:VideoEvent):void {
        trace("IN BUFFER");
        addChild(ButtonBlock);
}   
my_player.addEventListener(VideoEvent.PLAYING_STATE_ENTERED, startPlay);
function startPlay(e:VideoEvent):void {


        if(ButtonBlock)
            {
            removeChild(ButtonBlock);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thought would be to disable the ability to select another video as soon as you select one, and re-enable it once you're ready for the user to select another one. I don't know how your program is set up, so some more info there would be useful.

If you have several buttons, one for each video, then I would suggest simply having a boolean that each button checks before doing anything when clicked. Let's call it `loadingVideo`.

```
if(!loadingVideo) {
    loadingVideo = true;
    //(button's actions here)
} else {
    //(maybe a warning message here)
}
```

Once the video is initialized (maybe `VideoEvent.PLAYING_STATE_ENTERED`), you'll need to set `loadingVideo` to false again. That way if your user wants to change videos they can.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the number of buttons you have on stage at a given time, your best bet will probably be to disable each one individually:

```
buttonName.mouseEnabled = false; // disable the button
buttonName.mouseChildren = false; // disable any subclips to prevent them from also receiving clicks
```

If you DO want to take the draconian measure of disabling ALL buttons, you could use...

```
stage.mouseChildren = false;
```

Comment: Thanks this might be an option.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you are using multiple Video assets. why not just use a single Video asset tor ender all the videos? that why you won't ever be able to have two playing at once.

Comment: Do you mean only one videoplayer?

Comment: Yeah, one video player using a single Video and NetStream object. I just figured this was a playlist kinda thing.